# doctrine - generate model from db, but only a specified table?

Tags: doctrine

is it possible to generate models from db, but only specified tables in doctrine?

I can't locate a method in Doctrine_Core class for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line should work:

```
doctrine-cli generate-models-yaml path/to.yml
```

Look into the `Doctrine_Cli` class, it should have specified method.